# Unable to build: the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder coming when i have this in sdk

Tags: android, sdk, adt

i have dx.jar in my platform-tools folder in sdk but still problem is coming during run
Unable to build: the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder!

Comment: [what you have tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)  What you want exactly , do you want the jar file to be included in the application ?

Answer (score 0):

in Eclipse Tools (my app is Android API 19) i`m using:

- Android SDK Build Tools Rev 25.x (works for me).

In Android Studio (JebBrains) is too hard fall into this problem.